# Reparing Exchange 2003 edb files

Tags: exchange-2003, edb

Our Exchange 2003 SP2 got corrupted due to a RAID error, and unfortunately the back-ups are not up-to-date.

What is the best method of repairing the the Exchange `.edb` files with minimum possible data loss?

Comment: Seems like you've been having a bad couple of days :-( I got some bad news for you. I suspect that your database is beyond repair. Bad RAID usually doesn't make for recoverable database. How are your log files? You're much better off restoring your old database and replaying the logs.

Comment: Unfortunately the backups are 1 month old, and pretty useless. All the logs are fine, except the E00 - any idea how to sort this log out?

Comment: Btw, don't even ask about the bad days, we still in midst of them :-(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try running the ESEUTIL and ISINTEG utilities to try and repair/recover the database files:

http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Exchange-ISINTEG-ESEUTIL.html

Comment: Thanks, scanned the logs and found out the E00 is corrupted. Any way to fix this log, or replace it with good log?